# How to save images inside app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, alasset

Hi I'm new to iOS objective c.
I'm working on a app which fetches images and stores it in the app memory for reference.

1. when u click on the favourite it should go the favourites tab
2. when clicked on downloads.The image should go on the download tab.

as `ALAasset` is deprecated can some one explain what is the best way to store images.

is it using file or `PHImagemanager`.

and how?

Comment: are you want to Download Library Images ?

Answer (score 0):

You should store images in documents directory something like,

```
 NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *documentsDirectoryForSaveImages = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/ProfileImages"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectoryForSaveImages withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];  // This creates folder in document directory of name "ProfileImages"
```

Now you can store image something like,

```
 NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(responseObject, 1.0); //Convert image to data

 [data writeToFile:[documentsDirectoryForSaveImages stringByAppendingPathComponent:formImage] atomically:NO]; //write that data to path. formImage is string value (name of image. Ideally should use timestamp to make unique naming)
```

You can retrieve image something like,

```
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectoryForSaveImages stringByAppendingPathComponent:formImage]];
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: how can i add multiple images one after the other using this ..how can i retrieve those.